# how to resolve Uncaught TypeError using tableDragger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am having

> Uncaught TypeError: tableDragger is not a function

when using [tableDragger](https://github.com/sindu12jun/table-dragger) js library. The table-dragger.min.js file is well included and accessible from eclipse which means that the path is good.

This is how I am using it:

```
window.document.onload = function(){
    var test = function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('tableDragg');

        tableDragger(el, {
            dragHandler : '.draggable'
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try it using this way

```
var el = document.getElementById('table');

var dragger = tableDragger(el, {  
              mode: 'row',
              dragHandler: '.drag',
              onlyBody: true,
              animation: 300
           });
```

Add callback (events) if required